# xCode MongoDB Exec Bad Access

Tags: c++, xcode, mongodb

I have another problem with the configurations of MongoDB and Boost libraries.

Now seems it's all fine but when i try to run my simple project:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <mongo/client/dbclient.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //try Mongo
    mongo::client::initialize();
    try {
        mongo::DBClientConnection c;
        c.connect("localhost");

        std::cout << "connected ok" << std::endl;
    } catch( const mongo::DBException &e ) {
        std::cout << "caught " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

i get an Exec Bad Access on c.connect line.

This is the screenshot[image: Screenshot]

EDIT:
I run mongodb scons with this command:

```
scons --prefix=$HOME/mongo-client-install --extrapath=/Users/Wildregar/boost/ --osx-version-min=10.9 install
```

and in xCode in c++ Standard library I have

```
libc++
```

Comment: Same problem for me. I checked that my program, boost and libmongoclient are build with libc++ using otool. But how to check which language dialect is being used? In XCode my code is compiled using -std=gnu++11

Answer (score 0):

First, it is better if you post your example as a completely compilable example. However, when I added the necessary include and wrapped it in a main() function, your example code worked for me against a freshly built legacy driver.

Typically, these sort of crashes are the result of either a mismatch of language standard level (e.g. C++11 vs C++03) among the application, the boost library, or libmongoclient, or a mismatch of C++ runtime library, where some of those same components link with libstdc++, and others with libc++.

As a general rule, all components (the app, the boost libraries, and the driver) must be consistent with respect to language standard level and C++ runtime library.

Comment: Can you confirm that your application, boost, and the driver are all built with the same --std= argument, and are all linked against the same C++ runtime library (libc++ vs libstdc++)?

Comment: I run mongodb scons with this command: "scons --prefix=$HOME/mongo-client-install --extrapath=/Users/Wildregar/boost/ --osx-version-min=10.9 install" and in xCode in c++ Standard library I have "libc++"

Comment: Is libmongoclient.a built against libc++? You can tell by looking with the nm command to see, with nm libmongoclient.a | c++filt | grep std::__1

Comment: Also, is boost built against libc++?

Comment: I confirm the same problem. Everything is compiled using libc++ but how to check which language dialect (c++11, gnu++11, etc) is being used?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an easy way. Run the libraries through 'nm' or the OS X equivalent and look at the symbols? If you see things with &&, or types that only exist in C++11, then it was probably built in C++11 mode. You should probably also run your application through valgrind and/or address sanitizer. Also, be sure that threads aren't making concurrent access to the database connection objects.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. As pointed out by @acm the problem is related to the Language Dialect.
While the [official documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver) suggests to compile using

```
scons --prefix=$HOME/mongo-client-install --osx-version-min=10.9 install
```

this is a bad idea since C++03 dialect is used by default.

Instead use

```
scons --prefix=$HOME/mongo-client-install --c++11="on" --osx-version-min=10.9 install
```

and this should solve the issue.